# Как правильно сверстать макет блока на flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть готовый блок, сверстал по макету. Однако я хочу перенести на flexbox, что бы проще было адаптировать. Как это сделать и можно ли не использовать отрицательный margin? Код и изображение прилагается.

Заранее благодарю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 1170px;
}
.au-sheet{
    min-height: 996px;
}
.about-us-container{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
}
.about-us-img{
    text-align: left;
    width: 555px;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 148px auto 0 0;
}
.about-us-section{
    width: 650px;
    min-height: 550px;
    height: auto;
    background-image: none;
    box-shadow: 2px -2px 8px 0 rgb(128 128 128 / 45%);
    margin: -625px 0 60px auto;
}
.about-us-section-elem{
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.about-us-num{
font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
font-size: 17.0625rem;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 0.9;
background-image: none;
margin: 0 auto 0 0;
display: table;
align-items: flex-start;
width: 417px;
color: #f6f6f6;
}
.about-us-h2{
    font-size: 3.125rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: -150px auto 0 82px;
    color: #313131;
}
.about-us-text{
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-weight: 400; color: #616161;
    margin: 48px 76px 0 82px;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-us" id="about-us">
    <div class="container au-sheet">
        <img class="about-us-img" src="images/about-us-image.png">
        <div class="about-us-section about-us-container" >
            <div class="about-us-section-elem">
                <p class="about-us-num">02</p>
                <h2 class="about-us-h2">About Us</h2>
                <p class="about-us-text">Analytics release series A financing launch party interaction design android angel investor. Vesting period social media sales conversion launch party rockstar incubator customer social proof graphical user interface technology supply chain. Non-disclosure agreement rockstar creative partner network launch party social proof paradigm shift long tail influencer&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
                    <br>
                    <span style="font-size: 0.9375rem; "></span>Monetization validation success. Seed round channels product
                    management. Customer non-disclosure agreement strategy
                    android growth hacking ramen buyer.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде вы сделали, что хотели, но не понятно зачем такие большие отступы.

Не пиксель пёрфект, но смысл должен быть ясен.

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.card .image {
  display: block;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.card .image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin: 0;
}

.card .info {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% + 40px);
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: -40px;
  padding: 4em 3em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.35);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.card .info::before {
  content: '01';
  font-size: 10em;
  line-height: .75;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card .info::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fc5f43 25%, #35c796 25%, #35c796 50%, #b37df5 50%, #b37df5 75%, #feba60 75%);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.card .info h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.card .info h1,
.card .info p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/RcfII4O.png">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <h1>About Us.</h1>
    <p>Analytics release series A financing launch party interaction<br>
    design android angel investor. Vesting period social media sales<br>
    conversion launch party rockstar incubator customer social<br>
    proof graphical user interface technology supply chain. Non-dis-<br>
    closure agreement rockstar creative partner network launch<br>
    party social proof paradigm shift long tail influencer.</p>
    <p>Monetization validation success. Seed round channels product<br>
    management. Customer non-disclosure agreement strategy
    android growth hacking ramen buyer.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```